# Corrupted graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, inspiron, visual-artifacts

In the weeks since I installed Ubuntu 14.10, I've been looking for a solution to the various graphical issues I've been experiencing, and none seem to work.
My laptop is an:

```
Inspiron 1440, 64-bit
Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz × 2
Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset
```

Whenever I turn it on, everything runs fine at first, but over time, perhaps caused by running full screen videos or playing certain games, the graphics will start to get a little weird.

The close/max/min buttons will get weird horizontal lines, that change when I hover over the buttons. The fonts on the titles, and in some windows will look corrupted, sometimes unreadably so, requiring a restart. Certain objects in games will look strange, while everything around them is fine. And while videos play fine, I've noticed that they'll become choppy in full-screen mode (but that might just be Chrome hogging resources).

Here's a picture of the buttons and some weird lines next to a window, and in that window, conveniently, are some lshw and lspci outputs:

[image]

I've tried downloading the latest drivers from Intel, and before that that latest xorg and oibaf drivers. Nothing made a difference, except when I finally managed to mess everything up to the point where I had to reinstall Ubuntu, so I'm finally asking for help.

Comment: Had a similar issue in a fresh 14.04, but kernel 3.16. Reinstalling X.Org worked for me. My machine uses an AMD card though.